# Number of socks?

Tags: mathematics, probability

This same problem also appears here:  http://perplexus.info/show.php?pid=9271

> A drawer contains a mixture of red socks and blue socks, at most $2014$
>   in total. It so happens that, when two socks are selected randomly
>   without replacement, there is a probability of precisely $\frac23$ that both
>   are red or both are blue.
>
> What is the maximum possible number of red socks in the drawer that is
>   consistent with this data?

Comment: When you say _precisely_, that is indeed an _exact_ value? And 2/3 is the chance of (Blue/Blue OR Red/Red)?

Comment: @oerkelens, here is a possible solution as an example: You could have 20 red socks and 5 blue socks. The prob of both red = 20*19/25*24 plus prob of both blue = 5*4/25*24 = 2/3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is:

> The answer is $1065$ red and $285$ blue socks.
>  Probability of getting same colours = $\frac{1065 \times 1064 + 285 \times 284}{1350 \times 1349} = \frac23$

Inequation and equations are

> $r + b \le 2014$
>  $r \ge 0, b \ge 0$
>  $3 \times (r^2 - r + b^2 - b) = 2(n^2 - n)$
>  Solving all, $r = 1065$, $b = 285$ and $n = 1350$